# Gmail API Error from Code Sample - a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Tags: python, api, gmail

I'm incorporating the Gmail API into a program that I'm making, and I'm getting an error that I haven't been able to resolve/that I haven't been able to find an answer to online. The relevant code is below, as well as the error:

```
from apiclient import discovery
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools
import base64
from email.mime.audio import MIMEAudio
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import mimetypes
import os

def create_message(sender, to, subject, message_text):

    message = MIMEText(message_text)
    message['to'] = to
    message['from'] = sender
    message['subject'] = subject

    return {'raw': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_string())}

def send_message(service, user_id, message):

    message = (service.users().messages().send(userId=user_id, body=message).execute())
    print('Message Id: %s' % message['id'])
    return message

def send_email(orders):
    SCOPES = 'https://mail.google.com/'
    store = file.Storage('gmail.json')
    creds = store.get()
    if not creds or creds.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secret.json', SCOPES)
        creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
    service = discovery.build('gmail','v1',http=creds.authorize(Http()))

    message_text = orders[0]

    created_message = create_message('from','to','subject', message_text)
    send_message(service, 'from', created_message)
send_email(['TEST'])


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_email.py", line 50, in <module>
    schoolPing(['TEST'])
  File "test_email.py", line 47, in schoolPing
    created_message = create_message('from','to','subject', message_text)
  File "test_email.py", line 27, in create_message
    return {'raw': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_string())}
  File "/Users/Andre/anaconda/lib/python3.5/base64.py", line 119, in urlsafe_b64encode
    return b64encode(s).translate(_urlsafe_encode_translation)
  File "/Users/Andre/anaconda/lib/python3.5/base64.py", line 59, in b64encode
    encoded = binascii.b2a_base64(s)[:-1]
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Comment: I am getting the same error. Seems to be a python 3 issue.

Answer (score 78):

Found a solution, replace this line:

```
return {'raw': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_string())}
```

with:

```
return {'raw': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_string().encode()).decode()}
```

Notice added **.encode()** and **.decode()** method calls.

First, *str* object is encoded to *bytes* object - **base64.urlsafe_b64encode** requires it in Python 3 (compared to *str* object in Python 2).

Then, the base64 encoded *bytes* object must be decoded back to *str*. This is needed as **googleapiclient** library will attempt to **json serialize** it later in code and that is not possible for *bytes* objects.

Comment: If you are adding binary attachment and following the code sample:

- you need to use `as_bytes` instead of `as_string`.  There is no need to call `encode`, but you still need to call `decode`.
- you need to add a call to `encoders.encode_base64` after you call `set_payload`

Comment: Thank you so much. Gmail API documentation should be updated with your answer.

Comment: As mentioned by @NicolasGaller 


`return {'raw': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_bytes()).decode()}`