# Ipython error in jupyter notebook, no stack trace

Tags: python, python-3.x, gmail-api

I'm using the code from here: [Sending email via gmail & python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37201250/sending-email-via-gmail-python)
Step 3, (my version shown below)

```
import httplib2
import os
import oauth2client
from oauth2client import client, tools
import base64
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from apiclient import errors, discovery
import mimetypes
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
from email.mime.audio import MIMEAudio
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase

SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send'
CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'client_secret.json'
APPLICATION_NAME = 'Gmail API Python Send Email'

def get_credentials():
    home_dir = "C:\\Users\\kelvi_000\\Documents\\Jupyter Notebooks\\"
    credential_dir = os.path.join(home_dir, '.credentials')
    if not os.path.exists(credential_dir):
        os.makedirs(credential_dir)
    credential_path = os.path.join(credential_dir, 'gmail-python-email-send.json')
    store = oauth2client.file.Storage(credential_path)
    #credentials = store.get()
    credentails = False
    if True: #not credentials or credentials.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
        flow.user_agent = APPLICATION_NAME
        credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
        print('Storing credentials to ' + credential_path)
    return credentials

def SendMessage(sender, to, subject, msgHtml, msgPlain, attachmentFile=None):
    credentials = get_credentials()
    http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
    service = discovery.build('gmail', 'v1', http=http)
    if attachmentFile:
        message1 = createMessageWithAttachment(sender, to, subject, msgHtml, msgPlain, attachmentFile)
    else: 
        message1 = CreateMessageHtml(sender, to, subject, msgHtml, msgPlain)
    result = SendMessageInternal(service, "me", message1)
    return result

def SendMessageInternal(service, user_id, message):
    try:
        message = (service.users().messages().send(userId=user_id, body=message).execute())
        print('Message Id: %s' % message['id'])
        return message
    except errors.HttpError as error:
        print('An error occurred: %s' % error)
        return "Error"
    return "OK"

def CreateMessageHtml(sender, to, subject, msgHtml, msgPlain):
    msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    msg['Subject'] = subject
    msg['From'] = sender
    msg['To'] = to
    msg.attach(MIMEText(msgPlain, 'plain'))
    msg.attach(MIMEText(msgHtml, 'html'))
    return {'raw': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(msg.as_string())}

def createMessageWithAttachment(
    sender, to, subject, msgHtml, msgPlain, attachmentFile):
    """Create a message for an email.

    Args:
      sender: Email address of the sender.
      to: Email address of the receiver.
      subject: The subject of the email message.
      msgHtml: Html message to be sent
      msgPlain: Alternative plain text message for older email clients          
      attachmentFile: The path to the file to be attached.

    Returns:
      An object containing a base64url encoded email object.
    """
    message = MIMEMultipart('mixed')
    message['to'] = to
    message['from'] = sender
    message['subject'] = subject

    messageA = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    messageR = MIMEMultipart('related')

    messageR.attach(MIMEText(msgHtml, 'html'))
    messageA.attach(MIMEText(msgPlain, 'plain'))
    messageA.attach(messageR)

    message.attach(messageA)

    print("create_message_with_attachment: file: %s" % attachmentFile)
    content_type, encoding = mimetypes.guess_type(attachmentFile)

    if content_type is None or encoding is not None:
        content_type = 'application/octet-stream'
    main_type, sub_type = content_type.split('/', 1)
    if main_type == 'text':
        fp = open(attachmentFile, 'rb')
        msg = MIMEText(fp.read(), _subtype=sub_type)
        fp.close()
    elif main_type == 'image':
        fp = open(attachmentFile, 'rb')
        msg = MIMEImage(fp.read(), _subtype=sub_type)
        fp.close()
    elif main_type == 'audio':
        fp = open(attachmentFile, 'rb')
        msg = MIMEAudio(fp.read(), _subtype=sub_type)
        fp.close()
    else:
        fp = open(attachmentFile, 'rb')
        msg = MIMEBase(main_type, sub_type)
        msg.set_payload(fp.read())
        fp.close()
    filename = os.path.basename(attachmentFile)
    msg.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=filename)
    message.attach(msg)

    return {'raw': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_string())}


def main():
    to = "to@address.com"
    sender = "from@address.com"
    subject = "subject"
    msgHtml = "Hi<br/>Html Email"
    msgPlain = "Hi\nPlain Email"
    SendMessage(sender, to, subject, msgHtml, msgPlain)
    # Send message with attachment: 
    SendMessage(sender, to, subject, msgHtml, msgPlain, '/path/to/file.pdf')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

with the difference from the other answer is on line 19, I've modified variable [home_dir] to:

```
home_dir = "C:\\Users\\kelvi_000\\Documents\\Jupyter Notebooks\\"
```

In addition to:

```
#credentials = store.get()
credentails = False
if True: #not credentials or credentials.invalid:
```

commenting out the declaration for [credentials] and modifying the if credentials aren't valid part. (lines 25-27)

Now the problem is:

```
usage: ipykernel_launcher.py [--auth_host_name AUTH_HOST_NAME]
                             [--noauth_local_webserver]
                             [--auth_host_port [AUTH_HOST_PORT [AUTH_HOST_PORT ...]]]
                             [--logging_level {DEBUG,INFO,WARNING,ERROR,CRITICAL}]
ipykernel_launcher.py: error: unrecognized arguments: -f C:\Users\kelvi_000\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\runtime\kernel-942a92b5-f8cf-4ec2-8348-138e4580d562.json
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 2


C:\Users\kelvi_000\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py:2918: UserWarning: To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.
  warn("To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.", stacklevel=1)
```

No stack trace, no line numbers, no ipykernel_launcher... just this stupid error that doesn't show anything when googled...

Using python3

---

update:
I've tracked the problem down to the line:

```
credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
```

in the function

```
get_credentials
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is totally baffling. The solution is you put the script in it's own python file because that's somehow different.

Then from jupyter notebook, you run

```
%run [your filename].py
```

and it works?!

```
Your browser has been opened to visit:

    [censored]

If your browser is on a different machine then exit and re-run this
application with the command-line parameter

  --noauth_local_webserver

Authentication successful.
Storing credentials to C:\Users\kelvi_000\Documents\Jupyter Notebooks\.credentials\gmail-python-email-send.json
```