# Where to keep your client_secret.json on windows machine?

Tags: python-3.x, oauth-2.0, gmail-api

I am working with OAuth, for logging into Gmail account and sending emails via python script.
I have downloaded client_secret.json file, The file is stored inside C:\Users\anuj.masand\ (Home folder).
While running Python script I am getting following error:

```
oauth2client.clientsecrets.InvalidClientSecretsError: ('Error opening file', 'client_secret.json', 'No such file or directory', 2)
```

I can see that the file is not available where the script needs it to be.
I have read clientsecrets.py file and got to know following code loads the file.

```
def _loadfile(filename):
try:
    with open(filename, 'r') as fp:
        obj = json.load(fp)
except IOError as exc:
    raise InvalidClientSecretsError('Error opening file', exc.filename,
                                    exc.strerror, exc.errno)
return _validate_clientsecrets(obj)
```

My code is jumping right into exception part.
My question is where to store client_secret.json file? so that interpreter can find the file and moves forward. Where does python really looks for this file?

Reference: [Script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37267330/6295832)

Answer (score 2):

According to this [quickstart guide](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python), you are to move the downloaded file to **your working directory**. With the file named as `credentials.json`, the guide implemented the file reading as:

```
# The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
# created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
# time.
store = file.Storage('token.json')
creds = store.get()
if not creds or creds.invalid:
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('credentials.json', SCOPES)
    creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
service = build('gmail', 'v1', http=creds.authorize(Http()))
```

Do ensure that the filenames completely match.

Comment: Thanks @jacque for reverting and for your time, i have figured it out. Instead of passing the file name i did pass the full path(where ever you save your file), it worked.Answer to my question is still away. Thanks anyway.