# Trying to create a Gmail API compatible message just does nothing and gives no errors

Tags: python, gmail-api

Gmail decided that SMTP was too simple so they had to block it and setup their own API with all the weird requirements around it. [This script](https://github.com/khaudio/mc-stock) which I was trying to use has now become outdated and broken. In an attempt to use it anyway I tried to [rewrite](https://pastebin.com/TxbNGxnv) it:

```
"""
Checks stock on specified items at Microcenter store locations,
and sends email notifications when changes are detected.
Applicably, it helps the user obtain rare items during shortages.
"""

from aiohttp import ClientSession
from async_timeout import timeout
from getpass import getpass
from re import search
from smtplib import SMTP
import asyncio

import base64
from email.mime.audio import MIMEAudio
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import mimetypes
import os

import pickle
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request



class Item:
    """
    Class for containing state of individual items; methods update state
    by awaiting update().

    Item does not need to be directly instantiated; Store will create one
    per provided url.
    """
    def __init__(self, storeNum, url):
        self.storeNum, self.url = storeNum, url
        self.sku = self.price = self.stock = None
        self.stockChanged = self.priceChanged = False
        self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    def __str__(self):
        stock = 'in' if self.stock else 'out of'
        return f'SKU {self.sku} is {stock} stock for {self.price} at Microcenter {self.storeNum}\n{self.url}\n'

    async def pull(self):
        async with ClientSession() as session:
            async with timeout(10):
                async with session.get(self.url, params={'storeSelected': self.storeNum}) as response:
                    return await response.text()

    @staticmethod
    def parse_lines(page):
        for var in ['SKU', 'inStock', 'productPrice']:
            reply = search(f"(?<='{var}':').*?(?=',)", page)
            if reply:
                yield reply.group()

    @staticmethod
    def compare(new, old):
        return (new != old and old is not None)

    async def update(self):
        data = tuple(self.parse_lines(await self.pull()))
        if not data or any(data) is None:
            raise ValueError('Data missing from request or store number invalid')
        self.sku, stock, price = int(data[0]), data[1] is 'True', float(data[2])
        self.stockChanged, self.priceChanged = self.compare(stock, self.stock), self.compare(price, self.price)
        self.stock, self.price = stock, price


class Store:
    """
    Periodically checks a given list of urls for stock changes

    A store number is required to get accurate stock numbers.
    The default store number is set to the North Dallas/Richardson, TX location.

    Also required is valid email account information for notifications.
    If a recipient address is not provided, the user will be prompted for one.
    If the prompt is empty, notifications are sent from the sender
    address to itself.  Providing an empty string for recipient is a valid
    argument to enable loopback operation, as only a value of None
    will trigger a prompt.

    The default time between checks is 15 minutes.  This value should
    be at least a few minutes, to avoid being blacklisted by the
    server, though this class enforces no such limit.  To change the
    time period, provide a value in minutes to self.run(minutes).

    Setting debug to True enables false positives for testing
    """

    def __init__(
            self, storeNum=131, sender=None,
            recipient=None, debug=True, service=None
        ):
        self.storeNum = storeNum
        self.items, self.newInStock, self.totalInStock = set(), 0, 0
        self.debug = debug
        if not sender:
            self.sender = input('Enter sender email address: ').lstrip().rstrip()
        else:
            self.sender = sender
        if recipient is None:
            prompted = input('Enter recipient email address (leave blank for loopback): ').lstrip().rstrip()
            if not prompted:
                self.recipient = self.sender
            else:
                self.recipient = prompted
        else:
            self.recipient = self.sender

        #Google API BULLSHIT
        SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly']
        creds = None
        # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
        # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
        # time.
        if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
            with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
                creds = pickle.load(token)
        # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
        if not creds or not creds.valid:
            if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
                creds.refresh(Request())
            else:
                flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                    'credentials.json', SCOPES)
                creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
            # Save the credentials for the next run
            with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
                pickle.dump(creds, token)

        self.service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)

        # Call the Gmail API
        results = self.service.users().labels().list(userId='me').execute()
        labels = results.get('labels', [])

        if not labels:
            print('No labels found.')
        else:
            print('Labels:')
            for label in labels:
                print((label['name']))

        self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    def __str__(self):
        return '\n'.join(item.__str__() for item in self.items)

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self.loop.close()

    @property
    def storeNum(self):
        return self._storeNum

    @storeNum.setter
    def storeNum(self, val):
        """
        Check to see if value is formatted properly
        storeNum must be sent as a string, but should contain an integer.
        """
        assert isinstance(val, (int, str)), 'Store number must be an integer or string of integer'
        try:
            num = int(val)
        except:
            raise
        else:
            self._storeNum = str(num)

    @property
    def sender(self):
        return self._sender

    @sender.setter
    def sender(self, val):
        assert val is not None, 'Sender address cannot be empty'
        assert isinstance(val, str), 'Must be str'
        self._sender = val

    def run(self, minutes=5):
        run = asyncio.ensure_future(self.check(minutes))
        self.loop.run_forever()

    async def check(self, minutes=5):
        assert isinstance(minutes, (int, float)), 'Minutes must be an integer or float'
        seconds = minutes * 60
        while True:
            print('Checking stock...')
            await self.update()
            if self.newInStock:
                print('New items available')
                msg = email_message()
                print("message created")
                self.send_email(msg)
                print("email send attempted")
                #if sent:
                    #print('Recipient notified of stock changes')
            else:
                print('Stock unchanged')
            await asyncio.sleep(seconds)

    def add_interactive(self):
        entry = True
        while entry:
            entry = eval(input('Add one or more URLs separated by spaces, or leave blank to complete: '))
            try:
                urls = entry.split()
            except:
                if entry and 'http' in entry:
                    self.add(entry.lstrip().rstrip())
            else:
                self.add(*urls)


    def add(self, *urls):
        for url in urls:
            assert isinstance(url, str), 'URL must be a string'
            if url not in (item.url for item in self.items):
                new = Item(self.storeNum, url)
                self.loop.run_until_complete(new.update())
                self.items.add(new)

    def remove(self, *urls):
        for url in urls:
            assert isinstance(url, str), 'URL must be a string'
        self.items = set([item for item in self.items if item.url not in urls])

    def email_message(self):
        if self.debug:
            new = self.items
        else:
            new = tuple([item for item in self.items if item.stockChanged])
        message_text = '\n'.join(item.__str__() for item in new)
        print(message_text)
        #Create message container
        message = MIMEMultipart('alternative') # needed for both plain & HTML (the MIME type is multipart/alternative)
        message['Subject'] = self.email_subject()
        print("set Subject")
        message['From'] = self.sender
        print("set sender")
        message['To'] = self.recipient
        print("set recipient")

        #Create the body of the message (a plain-text and an HTML version)
        message.attach(MIMEText(message_text, 'plain'))
        print("attached plaintext")
        message.attach(MIMEText(message_text, 'html'))
        print("attached html")

        raw_message_no_attachment = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_bytes())
        print("encoded b64")
        raw_message_no_attachment = raw_message_no_attachment.decode()
        print("decoded raw")
        body  = {'raw': raw_message_no_attachment}
        print("set body")
        return body

    def email_subject(self):
        return f'({self.newInStock} new, {self.totalInStock} total) items in stock at Microcenter {self.storeNum}'

    def send_email(self, msgOBJ):
        message = msgOBJ
        print("message encoded")

        try:
            message_sent = (self.service.users().messages().send(userId='me', body=message).execute())
            message_id = message_sent['id']
            # print(attached_file)
            print (f'Message sent (without attachment) \n\n Message Id: {message_id}\n\n Message:\n\n {message_text_plain}')
            # return body
            return True
        except errors.HttpError as error:
            print (f'An error occurred: {error}')
            return False

    async def update(self):
        for item in self.items:
            await item.update()
        if self.debug:
            self.newInStock = self.totalInStock = len(self.items)
        else:
            self.newInStock = sum(item.stockChanged for item in self.items)
            self.totalInStock = sum(item.stock for item in self.items)


class Clerk(Store):
    """
    Further abstraction and automation of Store

    Instantiate Clerk with a list of urls as arguments
    and an optional store number as a keyword argument.

    Clerk exists to be able to start and run a Store in one line.

    The user will be prompted for email account information.
    """

    def __init__(self, *urls, storeNum=131):
        super().__init__(storeNum=storeNum)
        if urls:
            super().add(*urls)
        else:
            super().add_interactive()
        super().run()

Clerk("https://www.microcenter.com/product/616858/amd-ryzen-9-3950x-35ghz-16-core-am4-boxed-processor", storeNum=155)
```

I wrote this in a way that is Python 3.6 compatible and Gmail API friendly so it'll actually work. However, upon calling the Store.email_message method (which is supposed to create and return the necessary b64 encoded message object) nothing happens, not one of the prints spaced throughout it is called and no error is returned either. It just stops there.

I initially tried the code from the examples in the Gmail API Documentation, but that didn't work, so then i went searching through the web until I decided to stop with the code I got [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43379469/10501060) (code stolen from their send_Message_without_attachment and create_message_without_attachment functions) and ask for help.

### Edit

I followed the advice of the answer I got and changed the email_message function to

```py
    def email_message(self):
        if self.debug:
            new = self.items
        else:
            new = tuple([item for item in self.items if item.stockChanged])
        message_text = '\n'.join(item.__str__() for item in new)
        print(message_text)

        #Create message container
        message = MIMEMultipart('alternative') # needed for both plain & HTML (the MIME type is multipart/alternative)
        message['Subject'] = self.email_subject()
        message['From'] = self.sender
        message['To'] = self.recipient

        #Create the body of the message (a plain-text and an HTML version)
        message.attach(MIMEText(message_text, 'plain'))
        message.attach(MIMEText(message_text, 'html'))

        raw_message_no_attachment = urlsafe_b64encode(bytes(message))
        raw_message_no_attachment = raw_message_no_attachment.decode()
        body  = {'raw': raw_message_no_attachment}
        return body
```

That said it still gives no error and doesn't even get to print the message text when it gets to the point where it's called, so I'm still pretty lost.

Answer (score 0):

For the encoding you have to change your import and use like this:
Import:

```
from base64 import urlsafe_b64encode
```

Use:

```
encode = urlsafe_b64encode(bytes(message))
```

For the scopes using this one is more than enough:

```
SCOPES = ['https://mail.google.com/']
```

---

Remember to delete and renew the token.pickle every time you change the scopes.

Be sure that the API credentials are Ok.

Comment: so I know for sure the API credentials are checking out fine, thats why I added the label printing part just to make sure, but I tried using your method to encode and the program still just, does nothing when it gets to running email_message(). so there's a problem somewhere in there and I can't for the life of me figure it out

Comment: The function email_message(self) has self as a parameter. but when you are calling it on msg = email_message() you don't pass the parameter. Have you tried it?